# Can we have multiline comments in a Java properties file?

Tags: java, properties, comments

In a Java `.properties` file we can do single line comments with `#`.

Is there any way by which we can do multi-line comments?

Comment: select the lines and presss Ctrl + /

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Unfortunately not!  Java properties file only have single line `#` comments.

Comment: Useful info..There should be some way to do multiline comments for properties files too like java/xml/jsp etc..

Comment: but in this case?: https://serverfault.com/questions/1093174/how-to-disable-lines-in-java-security-for-linux-and-windows

Answer (score 43):

If you use Eclipse, you can select multiple lines and comment all with a shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> by default). Same shortcut uncomments the lines, but you have to pay attention no to select any empty line, which will cause the non-empty ones to get commented more than once.

These apply to Eclipse, but I guess many IDE:s and some editors offer similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut.I am fine with using eclipse, and letting eclipse auto-generate the multi-line comment.

Comment: Very useful. Thanks.

Comment: What about intellij IDEA, there is any shortcut to comment properties file?

Comment: Yes, there is, search for `comment with line comment` in Preferences > Keymap. It  should probably be `Ctrl + /` (`Cmd + /` for mac).

Comment: It works fine with STS 4 IDE too!

Answer (score 10):

`.properties` files do not have multiline comments.

Since JDK 1.5 Properties have XML support, and XML format supports multiline comments. See [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Answer (score 5):

I have made a class that handles comments in properties.
Both general header comments and comments for individual properties.

Have a look at : [CommentedProperties JavaDoc](http://jhpropertiestyp.sourceforge.net/jhpropertiestyped/javadoc/dk/heick/properties/types/utils/CommentedProperties.html)

The jar file can be downloaded here : [Download jar file from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jhpropertiestyp/)

Answer (score 3):

We can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to comment multiple lines in properties file. But it will put `#` for blank line also.

Comment: You can't just state this as a general fact. Each editor has different default key mappings.

Answer (score 1):

Select the content to comment out and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> on the eclipse editor

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse there is this shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> that turns on selecting a column, so you can just drag through all the rows you need to comment and add `#` (this will add it to all rows). It will be the same when you want to delete the `#`. To turn off the column selecting mode you have to again press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Answer (score -9):

single line comment using  `#`

multiline comment using `<!--   -->`