# Multi-line comment in Ant build.properties file

Tags: ant, properties, comments

How to add a multi-line comment in an Ant build.properties file? Is it even possible?

I have a `build.properties` file with properties like

```
property1.value=a
property2.value=b
property3.value=c
...
...
property30.value=xyz
```

These properties over-ride properties in another build file. However, when I don't want to over-ride, I would like to comment out all these properties at once by using something like

```
/*
property1.value=a
property2.value=b
property3.value=c
...
...
property30.value=xyz
*/
```

instead of individually commenting out each property by using

```
#property1.value=a
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ant Property Files are Java Property Files. Java Property Files don't support multi-line comments. See: [Can we have multiline comments in a Java properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156600/can-we-have-multiline-comments-in-a-java-properties-file)